# Swords and wing flutter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, aerodynamics, aircraft, structural-beam

In order to retain structural integrity it is understandable that a sword has to be flexible enough to be able to absorb impact without shattering and rigid enough to not be bent due to it.

> Is this reasoning the fundamental basis for making wings flexible
> (intentionally designing flutter) as well? Or are wings flexible, thus
> introducing flutter (which will be aerodynamically undesirable, in at
> least a few cases), as a result of the economy  of design (a trade-off
> with manufacturing cost or other structural parameters such as
> weight)? The [wing flutter is most clearly visible on helicopter
> blades](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pu48f7s5Ru8&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: This might get a better answer on Aviation Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, wings are designed to carry the maximum load with a minimum of weight. This results in their being flexible; to make them perfectly rigid would dramatically increase their weight and thereby reduce the payload of the aircraft.

Aerodynamic flutter resulting from wing or control surface flexibility is then managed in a way consistent with minimizing the weight of the aircraft- often by simply prohibiting the plane to fly fast enough to trigger the flutter mechanism. Prudent design then yields a plane which will not sustain flutter at any speed up to its design maximum. In this case, an overspeed condition will trigger flutter.